Repair Improper Ceiling Fan Mount
I recently moved into a new place and moved a ceiling fan from one room to another that only had a light fixture. The fan box is the type where you mount the fan fixture directly to the joist, not to the box (like this https://www.legrand.us/wiring-devices/electrical-boxes/ceiling-boxes/4-inch-round-direct-mount-ceiling-fan-box/p/s109fan). The existing holes in the joist from the light fixture were not spaced properly for the fan mount, so I added new holes and screwed it in. However I realized that the fan I moved was not installed properly and used drywall screws instead of wood screws. They are #10 coarse thread, ~10 TPI, and only 1.5 inches long. I want to properly fix this with wood screws. I don't know the weight of the fan, but I think its less than 20 pounds. Because of the previous existing light fixture screw holes, I don't think I have enough space to create another hole.
What are my best options?
Can I use the existing hole with the same diameter screw, but longer? What about differences in thread spaces for the first inch or so that was previously threaded?
Do I go with a larger diameter screw?
Something else?
Thanks

If you're going to use #10 screws, fill the holes with a few toothpicks to tighten up the fit. The 1.5" screws are too short for the box and fan bracket because you'll need 1/4" to clear the box and 1/4" to clear the bracket so only 1" would be going into the joist. You'll want to use at least 2" screws so just get some #12 x 2" screws

I've never had luck with toothpicks on anything structural.

I've seen the toothpick suggestion, but wasn't sure about that in this case of something vertically mounted.

If I go with #12 x 2in screws, it doesn't matter if the threading is different than the existing #10 screw hole? The one size up is enough to ensure solid fit? Plus any length beyond the existing 1" penetration will be newly threaded.

@jason I wouldn't use toothpicks going from a larger screw to a smaller one but the same size never had a problem with.

@user257489  One size up will provide a tight fit plus 1/2" of new penetration.

If on a truss/joist, you will have a minimum of 3.5 inches of wood to screw into.
#12 screws should take care of any screw damage wood from the smaller screws.
Make sure no wires/cables are in the section of wood you are screwing into if using longer than 1.5 inch screws.
Cables are suppose to be no closer than 1.5 inches from the edge if in wood.
